# How to extend an interface

Tags: java, design-patterns, inheritance, interface

I am coding to interface.

I have an interface **A** and a class **B** that implements it.

I am told that I could override **B's** functionalities by extending it by **C** but I am asked to touch neither **B** nor **C**, and then later replace **B** with **C** as the implementation class of **A** in the configuration files.

I figure that I need a method that is not available in **A**, so I need to add a method to **A** that I could implement in **C**. But I am not allowed to touch **A**.

Could someone help me with how-could-it-be done?

Thanks.

**EDIT**:
**Example code:**

**A.java**

```
public interface A {
    void X();
    void Y();
}
```

**B.java**

```
public class B implements A {
    public void X() {//something interesting}
    public void Y() {//something not very interesting}
}
```

Now because I was not allowed to touch either `A` or `B` I had to write another class `C` and extend it from B to do my things.

**C.java**

```
public class C extends B {
    public void Y() {//overriding B's not very interesting Y and making it interesting}
}
```

Now I need another method  `void Z()` in **C.java** to do my thing but because I am coding to interface `A` if I add a method just on **C.java** while using `A's` reference variable I will not be able to call `Z()` so I will have to declare `void Z()` in `A` interface as well to use it like that but if I do that I will have to touch `A` which I am not allowed to. So how to get this issue resolved is what I've been trying to ask.

So essentially, I wont be able to do something like following:

```
A a = new C();
a.Z(); //can't do this
```

So is there any way for me to achieve something like that without touching A or B?

Comment: do you perhaps mean: **touch neither A nor B**

Comment: plus: why can't you have a method that isn't in the interface? This isn't Objective-C!

Comment: yes, I know that is possible in ObjC too, but it's more common there.

Comment: You can't touch A, B, or C and must replace B with C's implementation of A? This is impossible unless you can either alter C or extend C to D and replace B with your new implementation of D. You cannot add a new method outside of the interface A and expect it to be used by the default consumers of A's interface.

Comment: OK, but what did you mean actually?

Comment: " I figure that I need a method that is not available in A, so I need to add a method to A that I could implement in C.  " - what did u mean here? first you said you need a method not in A. Then you say you need to add that method to A!!

Comment: You are writing the class `C` right? then whats the problem?

Comment: maybe you need either B or C as abstract classes? then you need not implement all the methods in A in abstract classes. Is that what you want?

Comment: @silverback: Yeah, good question. If C has all the methods of A, it can be used

Comment: @Everyone: Am sorry for the delayed reply. I have edited the question for making it more clear. I am using Java.

Comment: @11684: Yes, I could not touch either `A` or `B`, so I had to write a class `C` and extend it from `B` to override some of the methods implemented in `B` but then I figured I needed a new method and because I am coding to interface, I need to have that method in `A` as well as I am using `A's` reference variable to call the methods and `A's` reference variable will not reflect any newly added method just to `C`.

Comment: Ah, guess you are on some grounds beyond me! @skip

Comment: @skip When you edit the question, please change the whole text and leave a question that makes sense on its own. Adding edits to the end does not help very much for the readers.

Comment: @11684: I've made a final edit with an example in an attempt to explain the issue am trying to resolve, in case its possible to do that Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I understand what you want. You have the following:

```
public interface A {
  // can't touch this
}

public class B implements A {
  // can't touch this
}

public class C extends B {
  // you want to add your own method
  void someNewMethod();
}

// And you wish to do this:
A foo = new C();
foo.someNewMethod();
```

If this is what you want, then I'm afraid it cannot be done. Anyone working with `A` only knows about the methods defined in `A`; they won't know you've defined `someNewMethod()` in your class `C`. You need to be allowed to change `A`.

Note that in extremis,  you could check the class type of instances of `A`:

```
A foo;
// ...

if (foo instanceof C) {
  ((C) foo).someNewMethod();
}
```

but that is *really ugly* and breaks many of the cardinal rules of OO programming.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if you're allowed to do this, but you can extend interfaces as well as classes, you could do:

public interface A2 extends A {
    public void mySuperVeryInterestingNewMethod();
}

Comment: This could be done but the thing is the application am working on has so many instances of `A` that it can't be imagined to replace all the instances of `A` by `A2`. There wasn't any other option so I had to declare the method in interface `A` itself. Thanks for the reply:).

Comment: Eclipse has a 'refactor option if you ctrl+click/right-click option. That isn't so hard! @skip

Answer (score 0):

So, according to what you just wrote, you can't touch A, B, nor C... so, extend C with D?

Then you can add whatever methods you need/want.

Comment: I can't touch just `A` or `B`. I created `C` for I had to override some of the methods implemented in `B`. The thing is that I coding to interface so am using a reference variable of type `A` but the implementing class of `A` could be `B` or `C` or `D but I've got to have that new method that I want to use declared in `A` for `A's` reference variable to use to call that method.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear at all. Is this is what you mean or what you want?

```
public interface InterfaceA
{

}

public class ClassB implements InterfaceA
{

}

public class ClassC extends ClassB
{

}

public class ClassD extends ClassC
{

}

public class Main
{
    protected InterfaceA A;

    public Main()
    {
        //A = new ClassB();
        A = new ClassD();
    }


    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't touch just `A` or `B`. I created `C` for I had to override some of the methods implemented in `B`. The thing is that I coding to interface so am using a reference variable of type `A` but the implementing class of `A` could be `B` or `C` or `D but I've got to have that new method that I want to use declared in `A` for `A's` reference variable to use to call that method.

Answer (score 0):

If the method is supportive you don't need to add it to an interface to implement it. If it is used elsewhere then B implements another interface D.

Comment: The whole issue here is coding to interface `A`. At the client front I am using A's reference variable to call methods.

Comment: I think I follow. You have a variable which is of type A. You know it is a B and you need to call a method that isn't in A's interface. You need to either reference B directly instead of referencing the generalization A or attempt try to cast to B and handle errors casting

Answer (score 0):

This might solve your problem:

```
package test;

public interface A {

    void X();
    void Y();

}


package test;

public class B implements A{

    @Override
    public void X() {

        System.out.println("Something X");

    }

    @Override
    public void Y() {

        System.out.println("Something Y");
    }



}

package test;

public class C extends B implements A{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        A a=new C();
        a.X();
        a.Y();

    }

}
```

As per your requirement

1-You have created an interface A.

2-Created a class B which implement A.

3-created a class C which extends B and implements A.

4- A a=new C() will create a reference variable of type A but at runtime it will hold the object of C.

Since you cannot touch B and C the signatures are the same and you are calling X() and Y() from B using object of C as it extends B.

Hence you have replaced B with C without implementing X and Y in C and making changes to B.

Output :

```
Something X
Something Y
```

Hope this answer your question.